# How to save in framework

Tags: ios, security, keychain

I have created a framework in iOS, now I want to save some data within the framework so that the app don't have access in that and library can change the data whenever required , what is the best possible way to do it , taking all security issues into consideration ?

Comment: why u are down rating it ?

Answer (score 1):

The only way of making it private to the framework/library is to encrypt the data as the app has the same level of access to files as the framework/library.

Also note that data is not saved into the framework itself, but into one of the many folders made available to the app (i.e. `Application Support`, `Caches`, `Documents`, etc.).

I don't know what you mean by "taking all security issues into consideration", however if you mean "make it impossible to access" then that won't happen as you will need to use a key to encrypt the data and it won't be possible to hide the key from a dedicated and skilled attacker.  You will deter the casual user, however.

Comment: Thanks for your response trojanfoe , I have saved the data in keychain and it is working fine .